# How are Environment Variables used with Gatsby?

Tags: environment-variables, provisioning, gatsby

In the context of GatsbyJS, how are environment variables supposed to be used? I've read and re-read the [official docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/) but I'm still confused.

Specifically:

- Does Gatsby *automatically* read the `.env.development` file when doing `gatsby develop`?
- Similarly, does it ignore the `.env.development` file and only read the `.env.production` when doing `gatsby build`?
- Are you supposed to add `.env.development` and `.env.production` to `.gitignore`?
- Are you supposed to *manually* copy (e.g. via `scp`) the `.env.*` files to your servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `.env.development` and `.env.production` files, but didn't need [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) because I wasn't trying to get these env variables into node.js. I wanted these environment variables in JS files.

**Q1)** Yes. If you make an .env.development file in the root directory, add this one line of code `IMG_URL=https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1079`, and then in your JS add this line of code `<img src={'${process.env.IMG_URL}'} alt="" />` in a `render(){}` function in one of your react components. Then `gatsby develop`, you'll see the image

**Q2)** Yes it appears to. I created `.env.development` and `.env.production` files, defined a variable in the development one, then deployed to production. The env variable wasn't defined in the .env.production file.

**Q3)** hmm this probably depends on your repo. If it's a public or private. As well as the contents of the file. If you're using the .env files for API URLs etc.. that's fine, but Secrets shouldn't be in the .env files or the repo.

**Q4)** I'd say that committing and deploying are generally different. Unless you have a setup with auto deployments on commit. I have added my files to my .gitignore then copy all my local files to my live server. Maybe someone else has a better answer to this one.

Maybe this approach might be better for you [alternative config](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/660) go to `oliverbenns` comment

Comment: Are files' (i.e. `.env.production`) contents read into the bundle at build time and thus not actually necessary on the hosting server?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I tested this by adding the two .env files. 
`.env.development` had the following contents
`IMG_URL=https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1080`
`.env.production` had the following contents
`IMG_URL=https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1079`
After a `gatsby build`, when searching in the /public folder I noticed it had built the `.env.production` URL into the static files

Comment: Also, you should upload your /public folder to the server, your .env files should be in the root directory of your project. So they won't make it to the server.